# Angular 8 - 404 component overrides some of the other redirect paths

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-routing, angular8

I am working on 2 angular apps that have an external common directory for services/components or other shared stuff.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AokPageNotFoundComponent } from './aok-page-not-found.component';
import { CmsPageGuard } from '@spartacus/storefront';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '**',
    component: AokPageNotFoundComponent,
    canActivate: [CmsPageGuard],
    data: { pageLabel: 'notFound', cxPath: 'pageNotFound' }
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  declarations: [AokPageNotFoundComponent],
  exports: [AokPageNotFoundComponent]
})
export class AokPageNotFoundModule {}
```

Above is the **PageNotFoundComponent** which is found in the external common directory for both apps.

```
import { RoutesConfig, RoutingConfig } from '@spartacus/core';

export const aokCpRoutesConfig: RoutesConfig = {
  home: { paths: [''] },
  logout: { paths: ['logout'] },
  courseoverview: {
    paths: ['courses/:courseCode'],
    paramsMapping: { courseCode: 'code' }
  },
  mydataoverview: {
    paths: ['mydataoverview']
  },
  billings: {
    paths: ['billings']
  },
  courses: {
    paths: ['courses']
  },
  dashboard: {
    paths: ['dashboard']
  },
  product: {
    paths: ['product/:productCode', 'product/:name/:productCode']
  },
  notFound: {
    paths: ['**', 'notFound']
  }
};

export const aokCpRoutingConfig: RoutingConfig = {
  routing: {
    routes: aokCpRoutesConfig
  }
};
```

This is the routing config for one of the apps. The problem I am having is that the **notFound** path overrides this: **paths: ['product/:productCode', 'product/:name/:productCode']**
It does not override the simple paths like home or mydataoverview for example.

Does anyone have some advice on how should I tackle this issue?